# Getting error on installing polyglot for python 3.5?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, polyglot

HI i want to install the polyglot on python version 3.5. it requires to have numpy installed which i already have and also libicu-dev. My OS is windows X86. I went through cmd, pip and wrote "pip install libicu-dev" but it gives me an error that could not find a version to satisfy the requirements.
how can i install libicu-dev?

Answer (score 2):

For install polyglot, get all dependency libraries (.whl) from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

- NumPy
- PyICU
- PyCLD2

Install by `pip install <name_of_the_binary>.whl`

Related to issue 11 in poliglot github repository
[source_issue](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/11#issuecomment-126675914)

Answer (score 0):

From here:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy libicu-dev
```

for more information:
http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try:

```
git clone https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git 
python setup.py install
```

Then pip install:

```
pip install pycld2-0.31-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install PyICU-1.9.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work by typing it on Anaconda Prompt:
 pip install polyglot==14.11